# Como pegar o último digito de um número no ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

Tenho uma variável com um valor qualquer (`var qtdd = 758`) dentro de uma função e gostaria de pegar somente o último dígito desta variável, no caso o número **8**. Alguém sabe como fazer isso no ActionScript 3?

Segue o código:

```
this.addEventListener("tick", capta_x.bind(this));

function capta_x() {

    var qtdd = 758;

}
```

Comment: Poste o código pra facilitar a quem possa te ajudar amigo

Comment: Acrescentei. Obg amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divida o numero por 10 e pegue somente o resto da divisão, mas como o `%` serve justamente para retornar o resto da divisão, o primeiro calculo e desnecessário:

```
function capta_x() {
    var qtdd = 758;
    return qtdd % 10;
}
```

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma, Em AS3 :

```
var qtdd = 758;
var qtddString:String = qtdd.toString(); // converte para string
var ultimoChar = qtddString.charAt(qtddString.length - 1)); // pega o ultimo character e retorna "8"
var ultimoNum = Number(ultimoChar); // converte para numero e retorna 8
```